# Keyless car won't shut down

Tags: electronics, peugeot

My car , a keyless car Peugeot 4008, won't start or shut down. The first time , when I pressed start, the screen light up then the swippers and lights turned on and won't stop and everything stopped responding (I can't turn off/ change light light, stop swippers, start the car).I'm not even able to start the engine and not even able to stop the car. Any idea what can I do? I tried every buttons, hold start for 5 sec but nothing works

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair!

Comment: I'd start with resetting your fuse panel.  Then checking if there's any error codes being thrown or blown fuses (especially those associated with the remote control modules.

Comment: thank you Tom, I ended up leaving everything on to drain the battery, then jump started it when battery was flat. It works for now but I'll update later to see if it's truly fixed

Comment: That's really bad for the battery. You should have simply disconnected the battery's positive terminal

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your windshield wipers are running as soon as your put power on the car it is a clear sign of a **bus communication problem**.

### Background

Windshield wipers are a **safety critical feature** of your car. There is a connection between the windshield wiper and the wiper lever at your steering wheel that the lever used to tell the wiper to wipe or to stop. If that connection would drop, e.g. because a wire is broken, the windshield wiper **turns on by default** to always ensure that you have a clear view. Imagine your wipers turning off from one second to another during heavy rain.

The same reason that prevents your wiper lever to tell the wiper to stop wiping is preventing the start button from telling your engine to start.
In your dashboard probably a lot of lights show up as well.

### Fix

Simplest reason is, that a connector on an ECU got lose and needs to be replugged. However this only rarely happens.

Another possibility is a lose connection of single wires in a connector or broken wires.

Next possibility to look after would be a **blown fuse** that leaves an ECU without power. This happens often.

Further, more expensive reasons include broken ECUs (either broken hardware or broken software - it happens from time to time).

I'd suggest to first check your fuses and replace any blown fuse with a new one. You can safely do this on your own.

If that doesn't help, let a professional garage or somebody with a Peugeot-Specific Diagnostic Tool take a look at the car. Communication problems can be narrowed down using the fault codes stored in different ECUs of your car.

Comment: Very helpful post, thanks you, unfortunately it's wasn't the fuse but the battery. It's now fine after replacing the battery.